# Where should mir bitte be placed in a Question sentence that have a dative pronoun and an akkusative object?

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun, dative, accusative-and-infinitive

I have two sentences:

1. Kannst du mein Mittagessen mir geben bitte?
2. Kannst du mir bitte mein Mittagessen geben?

Are both grammatically correct? Is there any rule governing the positions in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2. Kannst du mir bitte mein Mittagessen geben?

This is the standard sentence when you want to ask someone to hand the lunch over to you.

> 1. Kannst du mein Mittagessen mir geben, bitte?
>      
>      <sub>(Notice the comma before *bitte*.)</sub>

This sentence is [marked](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markiertheit). The position of *mir* causes it to be stressed, so that you could imagine that the sentence goes on something like this:

> Kannst du mein Mittagessen mir geben, bitte, anstatt es selber aufzuessen?

Comment: very well explained. What if I place mir just after du as in the first sentence but keep the bitte in the last after the comma?

Comment: @akshitbhatia When _bitte_ appears separated with a comma, then it functions as a particle. Otherwise it is an adverb that modifies the verb _geben_. The meaning of _Kanst du mir mein Mittagessen geben, bitte?_ is similar to that of sentence 2.